# Why does serial device only work on one USB port?

Tags: usb, serial-port

This is another question about some software called chirp. It is an amateur radio program for programming frequencies into your radio. If I type :

```
cd /dev
```

I change directories. From here I type:

```
ls
```

And I get this screenshot.[image: /dev_#1.png]

Then I type clear and plug the device in to the USB port. After this I put this I repeat the command:

```
ls
```

And as you can see, I can see /dev/ttyUSB0 now when I couldn't before. So the computer knows that is is there, but it doesn't recognize it when I start up chirp on this particular port. Per the instructions, I

1. Put the cable into the radio.
2. Put the cable into the computer.
3. Turn the radio on.
4. Start chirp.

Unfortunately I cannot show you the "radio button" it is hidden on the top. But when you point your mouse over the top it will say "radio" and have a drop down menu that says "download to radio" I try to do this and get this screenshot:
[image: Chirp]

It was recommended that I type these commands for further testing:

```
dmesg -T

lsusb
```

These are the screenshots for the first USP port:

[image: chirp1.1]

[image: chirp1.2]

And here are the screenshots for the second usb port:

[image: chirp2.1]

[image: chirp2.2]

And finally the last USB port:

[image: chirp3.1]

[image: chirp3.2]

From another suggestion I am listing this output. After I type this command:

```
cd /sys/class/tty
ls -l
```

I get this output, first with no serial device connected:

[image: No_USB]

And then with the device connected to each USB port. The information was not showing up in the screenshot, so I copied and pasted instead.

port 1:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 04:51 ttyUSB0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0

port 2:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 04:53 ttyUSB0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0

and port 3:

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 20 04:54 ttyUSB0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0

I did find one last clue from the last answer. After typing this command:

```
dmesg | grep tty
```

I discovered that all of them have different numbers connected to them.

[image: USB_1-2]

I don't know why, but I couldn't get a screen shot of the other two. However, this is the information that I saw:

8439.280901] usb 3-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0

9103.795822] usb 7-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0

Update: Now I have two working ports and the one that isn't working has moved back to the right hand side of the computer. The number value for this port is USB_7-1. Again, thank you in advance for all of your help.

Comment: Do steps 1, 2, and 3, then type (and show us) `dmesg -T` (only the last several lines) and `lsusb`. Repeat for the other USB port,

Comment: Does the device have an external power socket?  Can you try using it on a powered USB hub?

Comment: @ubfan1-no I am getting the same results on a USB hub that I am on the ports.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps there are some clues in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530096/how-to-find-all-serial-devices-ttys-ttyusb-on-linux-without-opening-them).

What's your output of `ls -l /sys/class/tty` with and without your device in the USB port?

Another way to determine what `/dev/ttyS*` your device is connected to:

```
sudo apt-get install getserial

sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS*
```

If you only have one connected device, it should be possible to parse the output of setserial to determine what port your device is connected to.

(external [source](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-out-linux-serial-ports-with-setserial))

If neither of these solutions work, I would probably try to filter the dmesg output, e.g. (assuming 'pl2303' is the giveaway string):

```
dmesg | perl -ne '/pl2303.*(tty\w+)/ && print $1,"\n"'
```

should print your ttyUSB device string that you may try to connect to instead of /dev/ttyS*.

Comment: Borlin-I tested minicom (some of the information in your links) but it will not save the configuration file. Do you have any ideas? Your answer is likely the one that I will vote but I still haven't resolved the issue.

Comment: BJ: Sorry, I haven't used minicom since Motorola 68000 what the hottest thing around, so no clue there. But have you solved the USB/tty detection problem? If not, could you list the output of `ls -l /sys/class/tty` x 2 and `sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyS*` here? (Perhaps `sudo setserial -g /dev/ttyUSB*` too, but I'm in deep waters here...)

Comment: No, I have not yet resolved the issue, but I believe the answer lies somewhere in your feedback. Now the working port is back on the right hand side of the computer. But I am running out of time, Sunday is always full. I will vote your answer.

Comment: BJ, in your own time of course. As far as I understand it, part of the device assignment during boot is *random*, so I am not surprised that your working port changes. My thinking is to figure out how to determine (after boot) what /dev entry correspond to your device. Let me know your progress here and I'll try to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

nice to meet another ham on here.  The adaptor likely shows up as a different serial port for each USB port you plug into.  That's what happened to me.  You might want to try different /dev/ttyS# values and see what works.

Good luck

Comment: @Daniel-thank you for your answer. Although not extremely new to Linux I am unsure of how to do this. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: I tried the above commands for each USB port they are all /dev/ttyUSB0. Still, if you know how to change them it may fix the problem.

Comment: Does the working port seem to be the one that it is plugged into the first time after bootup?

Comment: @Daniel-negative, I tried the experiment and it didn't work on one port. Now I have two working ports, the ones on the left hand side of the computer.

Comment: And do all these ports work with other devices?

Comment: Yes. I tested it on all three ports with a flash drive.